# Palindrome detection program not working properly

Tags: python

Basically, I'm trying to solve this Leetcode problem about detecting palindromes (numbers that can be read the same back and forth,) but it seems that my program detects -121 as a valid palindrome and that 10 is also a palindrome, even though for the former I have a conditional that explicitly automatically returns False for negative numbers, and that the other conditional I wrote such that it should detect 10 as not a palindrome. Can someone offer some insight to where I went wrong? Here's my code:

```
    class Solution(object):
    def isPalindrome(self, x):
        """
        :type x: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        L=[]
        n=0
        a=str(x)
       
        if x < 0:
            
            print("False")
        
        else:
            for z in a:
            
                L.append(int(z))
            while n < len(L):
                b=(-1*n)-1
                if L[n] == L[b] and n == (len(L)/2)-1:
                    
                    return("True")
                    print("True")
                    break
                elif L[n] == L[b]:
                    n = n+1
                elif L[n] != L[b]:
                    return("False")
                    print("False")
                    break
                else:
                    return("False")
                    print("False")
                    break
```

I'm just taking this directly from the box where you write the code in on Leetcode, so that explains the top stuff.

> > Hey, everyone! Thanks for helping me out. It seemed that changing the strings to Booleans did help out a lot, despite Leetcode accepting the strings anyways. I added in a caveat that automatically detects numbers of length one digit to be automatically true (as when it goes to else, the division rounds down and things get messy), and Leetcode accepted it! So, thank you all so much. Also, I'll make sure next time to make sure my code is indented properly.

Comment: A string is not a boolean, and printing `"False"` is not the same as returning `False`.

Comment: Please correct the indentation of your code so that we can help you with your problem.  It's also best to post complete, running code, even if the code doesn't run the way you want.

Comment: Ditto returning `"False"`. `"False"` ≠ `False`.

Comment: provide leetcode question number .

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to check numeric palindromes without converting to strings:

```
def numPalindrome(N):
    left,right = N,0   
    while left>right:  
        left,digit = divmod(left,10)
        if left and left == right: return True  # odd size palindrome
        right = right*10 + digit
    return left and left == right               # even size palindrome
```

This works by forming a left and right part and comparing them for equality.  The right part is formed progressively using the last digit of the left part.  If, at any point the two parts are equal, we have a palindrome.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of *print("True")*, you can directly *return True*

Here is a simple Palindrome() function

```
x = 123131 # some number
str(x) == str(x)[::-1] # compare it with its reversed
```

Comment: ...how does dumping `str(x) == str(x)[::-1]` into an answer without any explanation help OP? How does your answer clarify the actual difference between `"True"` and `True`? Please read [answer]. The goal isn't to provide something to blindly copy and paste, but to _help others learn_.

Comment: Well I realized that there was indeed a difference, the former being a string and the latter being the proper Boolean thing. Removing this solved the problem for some reason but now single digit numbers don't work hmmm